# Utility to view partial classes as if they were not partial

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a windows form and that was generated by visual studio. I added some additional things  and I would like to export that form so as a class so that it can be included in other projects. Is there a way I can export just that form class as 1 file as opposed to having to pull in both form.designer.cs and form.cs?

EDIT : I know you can copy and paste, I was wondering if there was a built in way to do this.

EDIT 2 : Consider I want to make a repository of forms I made for a large program, if someone wanted to see or change one one particular window did they could just go to the actual window and open it up and see everything as opposed to having to check both the .cs and Designer.cs

Comment: If you want to use it in other projects, why don't you just create it in a class library to start with?

Comment: Copy `form.designer.cs` into `form.cs`?

Comment: @ Jon, I want to use the form in more than one project. edit: Derp, I misread what you said the first time Jon. I want people to be able to see the source code.

Comment: @Aelphaeis isn't that the point of class libraries, to allow you to share code across multiple projects?

Comment: I misread what he said as I was trying to respond quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a `Class Library` i is meant for re-usability. But you will still need the 2 files if you want to be able to modify the interface visually. VS need them to display at design time. In the library just right click the solution explorer and choose `add existing item` then browse for the form your want and select the `form1.cs` and add that, the designer file should get imported automatically.